# warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

Tags: c, controls

I'm getting this error when trying to compile this Polish command-line calculator.

warning: control may reach end of non-void function
      [-Wreturn-type]
}

I understand the error message means that I might not be returning anything from the function but where is that happening ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void push(int element);
int pop();


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    int op2;


    while (argc > 1)            
      {


        switch(argv[1][0])  {

          case '1':
          case '2':
          case '3':
          case '4':
          case '5':
          case '6':
          case '7':
          case '8':
          case '9':
          push(atoi(*argv));
          argv++;
          break;

          case '+':
          push(pop() + pop());
          argv++;
          break;

          case '*':
          push(pop() * pop());
          argv++;
          break;

          case '-':
          op2 = pop();
          push(pop() - op2);
          argv++;
          break;

          case '/':
          op2 = pop();
          if (op2 != 0) {
              push(pop() / op2);
              argv++;
          }

          else
              printf("error: zero divisor\n");
          break;

          default:
          printf("error: unknown operand %s\n", *argv);
          break;

          }

     }

     printf ("%d\n", pop());
     return 0;

 }        




#define STACKSIZE 1000

int next = 0;             /* next free stack position */
int stack[STACKSIZE];

void push(int element)  {

    if (next > STACKSIZE)  printf("error: stack full, can't push %d\n", element); 
    else stack[next++] = element; 

}


int pop()   {

    if (next == 0)  printf("stack empty\n"); 

    else return stack[--next]; 
}
```

Comment: If you took the time to write an MCVE you'd see it immediately.

Comment: Youy function `pop` does not return anything if `if` block is executed . That can cause _UB_ .

Answer (score 2):

You don't return a value when your stack is empty in the pop method.

```
int pop()
{
    if (next == 0)
    {
        printf("stack empty\n"); 
        // return statement missing   
    }
    else
        return stack[--next]; 
}
```

You can return 0 (or a value that indicates that the stack is empty) here, but it is better to check if the stack is empty before you pop something. For example you could add a `hasNext` or `isEmpty` method or check the size before you call pop.

Comment: Maybe it's returning 0 courtesy of UB?

Comment: @user004325 I'm not fully understanding you, do you mean your program does not work or the code I posted? You just asked why you get the warning and this is an answer. Generally stack overflow is not for questions like 'here is my code, why is it not working', see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

If `next == 0` in `pop` then it has no `return` value while the function return type is `int`, this gives you a warning, you should make sure every control path has a valid return type when in a function that's not `void`, an example would be:

```
int pop()   {

if (next == 0) { printf("stack empty\n"); return 0; }

else return stack[--next]; 
}
```